# Getting a true(1) or false(0) from specific sql statement

Tags: java, mysql

I need help with the code below and getting it to return a true or false value. Any and all help would be appreciated.

```
    public synchronized static boolean checkCompanyName(String companyName,
        Statement statement) {
    try {

        ResultSet res = statement
                .executeQuery("SELECT `companyName` FROM `companys` WHERE companyName = '"
                        + companyName + "';");
        boolean containsCompany = res.next();

        res.close();

        return containsCompany;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Are you getting an error? Please provide more information and any errors. Also, if using JDBC, please use a `PreparedStatement` instead of how you're doing it now :-)

Comment: **Warning: SQL Injection Risk ahead!*** Use prepared statements. [See this](http://bobby-tables.com); read my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your query like this:

```
ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery("SELECT companyName FROM companys WHERE companyName = " + companyName);
```

Or you can either you `PreparedStatement` which is better then you did before

Comment: Look at the string I made, it doesn't have needless `` like you did, compare between them

Answer (score 0):

Two comments:

1. You only need to check if there's at least one row matching your criteria, so you can use [`.first()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#first%28%29)
2. Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Please read [this](http://bobby-tables.com) to learn more about it.

The easiest way to avoid SQL injection attacs is to use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). So let me strike two birds with a single stone and give you a solution using them:

```
/*
Check if the company exists.
Parameters:
  conn    -  The connection to your database
  company - The name of the company
Returns:
  true if the company exists, false otherwise
*/
public static boolean checkCompanyName(Connection conn, String company) {
    boolean ans = false;
    try(PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
            "select companyName from companies where companyName = ?"
        ) // The question mark is a place holder
    ) {
        ps.setString(1, company); // You set the value for each place holder
                                  // using setXXX() methods
        try(ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            ans = rs.first();
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            // Handle the exception here
        }
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        // Handle the exception here
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Suggested reads:

- [Bobby Tables: A guide to preventing SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)
- [The Java Tutorials - JDBC: Using prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a `PreparedStatement` (for that end pass the `Connection` in to the method). Also, you should retrieve the value from the `ResultSet` and validate it matches your `companyName`. Something like

```
static final String query = "SELECT `companyName` FROM "
    + "`companys` WHERE companyName = ?";

public synchronized static boolean checkCompanyName(String companyName,
        Connection conn) {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, companyName);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            String v = rs.getString(1);
            return v.equals(companyName);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```